# document.selection.createRange(), Error in Flow with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

I am trying to get the user selected text on a react page on mouseup event.

```
selText = document.selection.createRange().text;
```

on `npm run check` I am getting the erro : `selText = document.selection.createRange().text;
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ call of method`createRange`. Method cannot be called on`

How can I fix this error. This code is wroign fine if neglecting Flow error.

Answer (score 0):

The type definition for `document.selection` is defined as a possibly null value. Flow is telling you, you need to check for the existence of object `selection` before calling `createRange()` otherwise you may experience runtime errors.

For example, you could use an `if` statement to protect your code against a possible runtime error and resolve your type error.

```
let selText;

if (document.selection) {
  selText = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
```